# Русские буквы в LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Добрый день. В общем есть задача занести в LDAP пользователей. Заношу из из файла (ldif). Но все бы хорошо только русские буквы получается добавить. При добавлении русских букв LDAP пишет

> ldap_add: Invalid syntax(21)additional info: cn: value #0invalid per syntax

Где то читал, что необходимо файл с ldif кодировать в UTF-8 а русские буквы кодировать в base64. Пробовал но не получилось все равно. Возможно есть какой то другой способ внести русских пользователей. Для примера приведу текст ldif.

```
dn: uid=shevchenko,ou=People,dc=tov,dc=ruobjectClass: topobjectClass: inetOrgPersonobjectClass: posixAccountobjectClass: shadowAccountobjectClass: qmailUserobjectClass: sambaSamAccountobjectClass: deepofixuserobjectClass: CourierMailAccountcn: Шевченко Татьянаuid: shevchenkouidNumber: 1008gidNumber: 1000userPassword: {SSHA}XvNqnPzwIB9g3xbPPoN+lYgOE0JNiUJMhomeDirectory: /home/shevchenkologinShell: /bin/falseshadowLastChange: 15118shadowMin: -1shadowMax: -1shadowWarning: -1shadowInactive: -1shadowExpire: -1shadowFlag: -1mail: shevchenko@domainmailMessageStore: /home/shevchenko/Maildir/qmailUID: 1008qmailGID: 1000mailHost: localhostdeliveryMode: noforwardaccountStatus: activemailQuotaSize: 0mailSizeMax: 0sambaLMPassword: 6E9A9CB752F2F855DB2294261F598B4CsambaNTPassword: 33D2D01D8A74F01D34E4A6CDCE0E088BsambaAcctFlags: [U          ]sambaPwdLastSet: 1306264612sambaPwdCanChange: 1337800612sambaPwdMustChange: 1337800612sambaSID: S-1-5-21-3825789469-1479138690-1952092781-SIDsambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-3825789469-1479138690-1952092781-3001displayName: Шевченко Татьяна gecos: Шевченко Татьянаdescription: Шевченко Татьяна disableimap: 0disablepop3: 0disablewebmail: 0qmailDotMode: ldaponlygivenName: Шевченко Татьянаsn: .
```

Answer (score 2):

Из [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDIF):

> Значение атрибута записывается в7-битной кодировке ASCII и отделяетсяот его имени символом «:». Значения,не подходящие под эту кодировку,записываются в кодировке base64 иотделяются от имени атрибута символами«::»

Вот так:

```
<имя_атрибута>:: <base64_значение_атрибута>
```

Comment: Добрый день. Так если я введу значение закодированное в base64 то оно будет в base64 отображаться. Т.е. будет просто набор символов и букв английского алфавита но не русского. У меня ещё одна идея, может поменять тип этого атрибута в схемах, только не знаю как его поменять.

Comment: base64 - это и есть кодирование прочих кодовых таблиц в семибитный ASCII, и более того, способ упаковки бинарных файлов для пересылки их по электронной почте, и не только. К моему большому сожалению,  в LDIF другого способа кодирования не ASCII символов не предусмотрено.

Comment: Я ввел значения в base64. Но русским текстом это значение не стало. А мне нужно русское значение. Для примера приведу пример. Вот опустим я залил в LDAP значение:cname:: 0J/QtdGC0YDQvtCyВ из LDAP оно будет извлекаться как 0J/QtdGC0YDQvtCy. Тогда вопрос где тут русские символы? Смыл что я из в base64 перевел, хранится то оно в английских символах.

Comment: Приведите ваш текст ldif после изменения. Врать вам у меня намерения нет. Можете сами посмотреть RFC 2849: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2849 Там, кстати, примеры есть.

Comment: Вот к примеру мой ldif https://docs.google.com/document/d/1szDTKanGbfEqqd6_HitDhxq-CnhL52cLuYjF2ZJ58GM/edit?usp=sharingНо к примеру я залью туда base64 но нужно написать какой то декодер который этот base64 на лету декодирует обратно в читаемый текст.

Comment: По идее, декодированием должен заниматься сам клиент LDAP. Какой вы используете?

Comment: Какой клиент использую? Там скорее всего web интерфейс. Вообще я несколько клиентов использую Softerra LDAP Browser 2.6 или phpldapadmin. Да в принципе не важно где смотреть главное что отображается base64  в клиенте.

Comment: Я уже давал вам ссылку на RFC 2849 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2849), и писал что там есть конкретные примеры. Но вы этого читать не захотели! Между тем, найдите в этом RFC 2849 "Example 4"! Там ясно написано, как (на базе японского языка) можно это сделать.

Comment: @Александр Архипов: попробуйте в `base64` кодировать строку текста в кодировке `UTF-8`.